# How to retry the entire test class in TestNG?

Tags: java, testing, testng

I have a test case like this:

```
@Listeners({RetryListener.class})
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        //something
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test1")
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        //something
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test2")
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        //something
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are dependencies on the tests. I would like to retry the entire test class once there is anything wrong with the tests.

Is there a way to do it in TestNG?

My `RetryListener` looks like this:

```
public class RetryListener extends TestListenerAdapter {

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer() != null) {
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);

            if(result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer().retry(result)) {
                count++;
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
                System.out.println("Error in " + result.getName() + " with status "
                        + result.getStatus()+ " Retrying " + count + " of 3 times");
                System.out.println("Setting test run attempt status to Skipped");
            } else {
                count = 0;
                System.out.println("Retry limit exceeded for " + result.getName());
            }

            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you end up with an infinite loop?

Comment: I would like to limit the retry to 3 times.

Comment: What does your RetryListener class look like?

Comment: I have posted my RetryListener above. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713564/restart-failed-test-case-automatically-in-testng-selenium