# Retry only specific Failed tests with TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

How to execute only the specific failed tests. By using 'IRetryAnalyzer' we can re-run the failed tests for x number of time. As mentioned here [Restart failed test case automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713564/restart-failed-test-case-automatically-in-testng-selenium). I have also implemented iTestListener to make the tests count more meaning full by following [Retry Only failed Tests](http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/execute-only-failed-test-cases-using-iretryanalyzer) and [update test run count by implementing 'ITestListener'](http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/retry-listener-failed-tests-count-update)

**Is there any way to Re-run ONLY specific failed tests.**

**Example:** We need to execute only tests which are failed because of NoSuchElementException and TimeoutException.

Please find the below screen shot where total 8 tests are failed and there are 6 tests which are failed because of NoSuchElementException-1 and TimeoutException-5. 
[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try out by checking the result of your tests like:

```
@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
try {
    if (result.getThrowable().toString()
        .contains("NoSuchElementException")) // Checking for specific reasons of failure
        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
            retryCount++;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Since every result has an attribute `m_throwable` in case of exception has occurred, you can use it to get your task done in Retry class.

Comment: Super.. Let me try and get back.. Thanks a lot

Comment: I applied your solution and now work like a charm. thank You again.